# Change Item icon color in MoreController of UITabBarController swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have an issue related to `UITabBarController` following is my code to create `UITabBarController`.

```
 let tabBarController = CustomTabBarController() //custom controller
        tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = nil
        tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(named:"navigationColor") //tabBarColor
        self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

I have to display 6 items in `UITabBarController` but it can only display four and rest are displayed in MoreController managed by IOS which is fine.
Only problem is the two items listed in More controller have different icon color then the rest which are in tab bar controller.

See this image where Item's listed in more controller have different icon color then `UIControllerTabBar`.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/honV5.png)

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing tintColor in `tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view.tintColor`

So you can access UITableView if you study this question better. I changed not only the tintColor, but also the color of the selection of the cell when pressed.

It is worth considering that moreNavigationController may not exist at the time of the configuration - it may take a little time before setting up.